# Postfix is looking for /etc/aliases.db for some reason instead of using Postgresql db

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, email, postfix

I'm trying  to setup my Postfix + Devocot + Postgresql. For now just to be able to receive an email, somehow, and save it in the file system.

A part of my postfix/main.cf where I've commented out "aliases" and which hasn't changed anything:

```
    #  query to find which domains we accept mail for
    virtual_mailbox_domains = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf

    # query to find which email addresses we accept mail for
    virtual_mailbox_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf




    ######
    # disable aliases for now, just for testing

    # query to find a user's email aliases
    #virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_alias_maps.cf


    virtual_alias_domains =
    #alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    #alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
```

Log of Postfix:

```
    localhost postfix/master[30377]: terminating on signal 15
    localhost postfix/postfix-script[30489]: starting the Postfix mail system
    localhost postfix/master[30491]: daemon started -- version 3.3.1, configuration /etc/postfix

    localhost postfix/smtpd[30495]: error: open database /etc/aliases.db: No such file or directory # <----- WHY?????? Why not in Postgresql?

    localhost postfix/smtpd[30495]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
    localhost postfix/smtpd[30495]: connect from sender-of-o51.AAABBBCCC.com[11.22.33.44]
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: pgsql query failed: fatal error from host localhost: ERROR:  column "value" does not exist?LINE 1: select 1 from domains where value = 'my_original_good_email@gmail.com'?                                    ^?
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains: pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains: pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains: pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
    localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[30499]: warning: virtual_mailbox_domains lookup failure
    localhost postfix/smtpd[30495]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from sender-of-o51.AAABBBCCC.com[11.22.33.44]: 451 4.3.0 <my_original_good_email@gmail.com>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<my_original_good_email@gmail.com> to=<mail1@my_postfix_email_server.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<sender-of-o51.AAABBBCCC.com>
    localhost postfix/smtpd[30495]: disconnect from sender-of-o51.AAABBBCCC.com[11.22.33.44] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/6
```

I sent an email to it from my good email/gmail "my_original_good_email@gmail.com".

But why is Postfix looking for my *good/external* email in **its** "virtual_domains" table?

What's going on? Why " /etc/aliases.db"? How to disable them only for the sake of testing?

**Update**

```
  $ cat virtual_mailbox_domains.cf 
  user = postfix
  password = aaa
  hosts = localhost
  dbname = postfix_db
  query = select 1 from domains where value = '%s'
```

And

```
  postfix_db=> select * from domains
   id |      name       | description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with opening aliases database is unrelated, but the reason for it is that commenting `alias_maps` and `alias_database` out doesn't empty them but causes using default values instead:

```
# postconf -d | grep alias_
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
. . .
```

If you want to empty any configuration parameter, explicitly set it as empty in your `main.cf`.

Your actual problem is in your [PostgreSQL client configuration](http://www.postfix.org/pgsql_table.5.html) or in your database structure:

```
pgsql:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf: table lookup problem
```

The following error is what you really should be looking at, as it points out that the problem is actually in your configuration in `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_domains.cf`, which doesn't match your database structure:

```
warning: pgsql query failed: fatal error from host localhost: 
   ERROR:  column "value" does not exist?LINE 1: 
   select 1 from domains where value = 'my_original_good_email@gmail.com'?   ^?
```

Knowing the query used in `virtual_mailbox_domains.cf` and the headers from the output of `postfix_db=> select * from domains` we can spot two errors.

- As it says, there is no column `value` in your table `domains`. Instead of column `value` you have a column `name` which I suppose has the domain names.
- You are comparing the whole email address instead of the domain. According to [`pgsql_table`](http://www.postfix.org/pgsql_table.5.html) the `%s` is replaced by the input key while `%d` is replaced by the domain part of the address within the pgsql parameter `query`.

If you fix them both, my educated guess for the resulting query that might work would be:

```
query = select 1 from domains where name = '%d'
```

Comment: 1) how precisely set them as empty? I've tried `alias_database =` and 
`alias_maps = ` or using empty strings `""` in main.cf ----> nothing changed when I ran sudo postconf -d | grep alias_

Comment: That's because `-d` shows the **default** values instead of the current configuration.

Comment: Ok, updated my question

Comment: This confirmed that I was correct. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: i have other issues, this is solved for now

Comment: That's exactly how to use Q/A sites: for another issue, ask another question. :)